# How do I use JQuery to add an event to a textbox when the user pushes enter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

And please don't submit the form when the user pushes enter on THAT SPECIFIC textbox.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? I'm having a hard time understand what you're trying to do exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check enter key on keyup event,

```
$j("#idOfSpecificBox").bind("keyup",function(e1){
       if(e1.keyCode==13){            
          return false;
       }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the keypress event

Your textbox:

```
<input type="text" id="myText" />
```

Your script:

```
$("#myText").keypress(function(e) {
   if(e.keyCode == 13) {
      alert("pressed");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#("#id_textbox").keydown(function(event){
         if(event.keyCode == 13){
                //fire
         }
}
```

will this work?